# SQLite cross-platform in libgdx

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, libgdx, ormlite

If its possible to create SQLite database which support iOS and Android systems using `libgdx`? As far I know the `ORMlite` is not supported on iOS based devices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a SQLite database in Libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874824/using-a-sqlite-database-in-libgdx)

Answer (score 0):

As far, Libgdx can work with SqlLite-database. And SQLite is supported both android and iOS. :)
Check it out

> https://code.google.com/archive/p/libgdx-users/wikis/SQLite.wiki